# Using Castle Windsor child containers to resolve a type with a specific instance

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm currently using Castle Windsor's child container functionality to override the registration of a particular type with a specific instance in a factory method. I am using the child containers purely so that the registration is temporary for a single resolution - in other words, I don't want the registration to affect all resolutions for that type.

Perhaps some code will explain what I mean.

I have a Func which acts as a factory `Func<IReportCategory, IReportCategoryViewModel>` - I give it an implementation of an IReportCategory and it returns a new instance of an IReportCategoryViewModel. (IReportCategoryViewModel has a dependency on IReportCategory).

This is registered with Castle Windsor as follows:

```
        container.Register(
            Component.For<Func<IReportCategory, IReportCategoryViewModel>>().Instance(
                category => ResolveCategoryViewModelFactory(container, category)));
```

Where `ResolveCategoryViewModelFactory` is implemented as follows:

```
    private CategoryViewModel ResolveCategoryViewModelFactory(IWindsorContainer container, IReportCategory category)
    {
        using (IWindsorContainer childContainer = new WindsorContainer())
        {
            childContainer.Register(Component.For<IReportCategory>().Instance(category));
            container.AddChildContainer(childContainer);

            return childContainer.Resolve<IReportCategoryViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

What the above method achieves is the resolution of IReportCategoryViewModel, injecting the specific instance of IReportCategory as a dependency. If IReportCategoryViewModel has other dependencies that need satisfying, then these get automatically injected by the container.

I can subsequently use the Func as follows:

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly Func<IReportCategory, IReportCategoryViewModel> factory;

    public Test(Func<IReportCategory, IReportCategoryViewModel> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void ResolveTest()
    {
        // Create a category (note: this would probably be resolved from the container in some way)
        IReportCategory category = new ReportCategory();

        // Call into the factory to resolve the view model
        IReportCategoryViewModel vm = factory(category);
    }
    ...
```

**Question:** Does this seem like a suitable thing to do? From the impression I get, child containers are not recommended in Castle Windsor - is there another way of achieving the same result?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely there are better ways to go, and the code you're using right now has a bug - it will try to release all the component instances you're resolving when you dispose of the child container, therefore they might be unusable (disposed) before you even get a chance to use them.

If I understand your explanation correctly it feels like a job for [typed factories](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility.ashx).

Comment: Typed Factories are indeed a much better way to do this! Many thanks Krzysztof!

Comment: This doesn't quite result in the same behaviour as child containers - as it uses names to match the constructor arguments to the factory method arguments it only works for the type returned by the factory itself, which means that any of its dependencies don't get the instance passed to the factory method if they need it injected. Here's a gist that I've been using to explore this (which might explain better :) ) https://gist.github.com/1357829

Answer (score 4):

Following Krzysztof's advice to use Typed Factories, here is how I implemented the above functionality. It is far more simpler than using child containers!

Firstly, create a factory interface which defines the signature of the factory method:

```
public interface ICategoryViewModelFactory
{
    CategoryViewModel Create(ReportCategory category);
}
```

Next, ensure the `TypedFactoryFacility` is enabled in the container:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
```

Finally, register the factory interface with the container:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ICategoryViewModelFactory>()
        .AsFactory());
```

Now you can inject `ICategoryViewModelFactory` into your classes, and call the `Create()` method to create a new instance of `CategoryViewModel`:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(ICategoryViewModelFactory categoryViewModelFactory)
    {
        // This would probably be resolved by the container (it's like this for the example)
        ReportCategory category = new ReportCategory();

        // Get Windsor to resolve the view model using the factory
        ReportCategoryViewModel vm = categoryViewModelFactory.Create(category);

        ....
```

**Warning:** The parameter name in the factory method needs to match the parameter name of the constructor of the object the factory creates. In the above example, the factory interface defines the method:

```
CategoryViewModel Create(ReportCategory category)
```

The constructor for `CategoryViewModel` must also have the parameter named "category":

```
public CategoryViewModel(ReportCategory category)
```

This is because the factory method is the equivalent of the following:

```
container.Resolve<CategoryViewModel>(new { category = paramPassedIntoFactoryMethod });
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the code you used to resolve this issue - I spent a long time looking for an example just like this to help me. However I'm still stuck and hope you can help.  I have effectively copied your code and replaced a few words to make it appropriate to my objects and when I run the application, I get a `DependencyResolverException` for my equivalent to your `ReportCategory` object. The exception states that my view model has a dependency on the model which could not be resolved. Do you have `ReportCatgory` registered in Castle Windsor? If so, how?

Comment: I managed to get this working and have posted my code at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11604109/336752